# what type of button is more attractive and comfortable?

Tags: website-design

In web application , i see two types of button effects.

- like that of gmail - standard button without much effect
- like that of wordpress - that has a click effect where button looks like a real digital hardware button. (which has inset)

which button is more attractive or comfortable to users?

sometimes i feel the wordpress like button will look more attractive as a user..

Comment: Actually the Gmail buttons have subtle on hover and inset effects as well (and they "pop out" to appear as buttons on hover). It's most noticeable on the "dropdown" buttons where you can see them inset when you click them

Comment: @BenBrocka indeed , but i wanted to give a wage comparison to what my idea was, so in that case you can consider the one in UX itself!! :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sounds like a weasel answer I know but **it depends**. I'd say whichever approach is chosen should be used consistently through out the system. There is a heavy movement right now for "minimalistic" UI where the embellishments and flourishes to make the UI look more "realistic" are eschewed and just enough is placed to provide hints as to what a specific element will do.

A primary example of this is Microsoft's "Metro" design but the example you gave from Gmail fits well here too.

It all boils down to a matter of personal taste. As long as you don't have flashing text and animated "in construction" gifs, you're probably safe whichever approach you take.

I can give a good example of what not to do right here. The majority of the UX site uses flat, minimalistic buttons except the "submit" buttons. They feel out of place in the context of the rest of the site.